# just the right droop to the last two inches of it?

Tags: meaning

> There was a sourfaced Scottie and a mutt with all the skin off one leg and a silky-gray Angora and a Sealyham and two more mutts and a razor-sharp fox terrier with a barrel snout and **just the right droop to the last two inches of it**.

The above sentence is from "The Man Who Liked Dogs." written by Raymond Chandler in 1936.

I don't understand the meaning of the 'just the right droop to the last two inches of it'.

My guess is  the snout of the dog is just 2 inches short for standard droop of a fox terrier.

Am I wrong or right?

Comment: This fox terrier **has** the proper characteristics.  *just the right* means "exactly the right".  A **droop** would be a downward curvature.

Comment: In the US a purebred dog must live up to a breed standard in order to have official "papers" from kennel clubs which allow the animal to be put out to stud or to have a litter and pass on the purebred status. Animals which fail the standard in significant ways (e.g. shape of tail or ear is wrong, size is too small, coloring is off, etc) are often not permitted to be bred. I don't know if the fox terrier is supposed to have such a droop to its snout, but a breed standard is the most likely allusion there.  http://images.akc.org/pdf/breeds/standards/SmoothFoxTerrier.pdf

Comment: Here is a picture of what I suppose to be a "droop" to the snout: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1436&bih=1031&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=fox+terrier&oq=fox+terrier&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i67k1j0l7.2707.5949.0.6062.15.8.3.4.4.0.69.487.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.15.506...35i39k1j0i10i67k1.n1IXNFkZJ9s#imgrc=X86S3a3VgWHgpM:

Comment: Here's the wire-haired standard: http://images.akc.org/pdf/breeds/standards/WireFoxTerrier.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the "droop" refers to the snout at all because of the presence of "and." If it were referring to the snout, it would say something like "...barrel snout ***with*** just the right droop..."

If you look up the definition of droop, it shouldn't have anything to do with the snout. In fact, a droopy snout might indicate a serious physical deformity. On dogs, it is most common to refer to droopy ears, and occasionally to a droopy tail. Specifically, the breed standard for fox terriers defines the tips of the ears as droopy. My guess is that the author judges the terrier's ears to droop just as the breed standard defines, or that he personally finds the droop of it's ears pleasing in some way.

http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/smooth-fox-terrier/

Comment: But then what do you think *it* refers to, if not the snout?  It seems hard for me to believe that Chandler meant the ears when he said "just the right droop to the last two inches of it."

Comment: @stangdon As I said in my answer, I believe it refers to the ears. They are the only part of a fox terrier that is supposed to droop. Specifically, the last couple of inches of the ears.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are wrong.

It sounds like

> to the last two inches of it.

means including the last two inches of the snout.

It sounds like the phrase [To a T](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/to-a-t.html), which means "Just right" or "perfectly",
or [Down to the last Detail](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+to+the+last+detail), which means including the last detail.

It is a qualifier, but it is saying that while sometimes razor-sharp fox terrier's snouts are off by 2 inches, this dog's snout is just right, including even the last two inches.

Comment: How exactly would a dog's snout droop? If it's snout drooped, it would be deformed and no author would consider that appealing. Certainly not just right.